# Need to perform sum of element in an array of object by eliminating similar value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The input array i have below is the example array

```
var array = [
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"five"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"five"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"five"},
]
```

I have tried the below code to sum of value

```
const sumOfValue = array.map(item=>item.value).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
```

How can i filter/remove similar value based on key am looking for an output as shown below
The output should be sum of unqiue value base on key
output: 15

Comment: What unique value? consider using a "Set" object (once mapped)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first take out the unique keys and then iterate them through map, and accumulating via reduce.

```js
var array = [
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"five"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'online',value:5,section:"five"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'call',value:5,section:"five"},
]

const sumOfValue = Object.values(
  array.reduce( (c, e) => {
    if (!c[e.key]) c[e.key] = e;
    return c;
  }, {})
).map((val)=> val.value).reduce((prev, next)=>prev+next)

console.log(sumOfValue)
```

Comment: will face problem if all the value:is having same value for example value:5 in all the objects

Comment: The answer was based on your first question which didn't imply the need of key's being the unique factor. The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the mapped array into a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and transform it back to array, then calculate sum

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type

```
Array.from(
  new Set(array.map(item=>item.value))
)

// or
[...new Set(array.map(item=>item.value))]
```

```js
var array = [
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"one"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"Two"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"three"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"four"},
{key:'pos',value:5,section:"five"},
{key:'online',value:10,section:"one"},
{key:'online',value:10,section:"Two"},
{key:'online',value:10,section:"three"},
{key:'online',value:10,section:"four"},
{key:'online',value:10,section:"five"},
{key:'call',value:15,section:"one"},
{key:'call',value:15,section:"Two"},
{key:'call',value:15,section:"three"},
{key:'call',value:15,section:"four"},
{key:'call',value:15,section:"five"},
]

const sumOfValue = Array.from(new Set(array.map(item=>item.value))).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);

console.log(sumOfValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var array = [{
    key: "pos",
    value: 5,
    section: "one"
  },
  {
    key: "pos",
    value: 5,
    section: "Two"
  },
  {
    key: "pos",
    value: 5,
    section: "three"
  },
  {
    key: "pos",
    value: 5,
    section: "four"
  },
  {
    key: "pos",
    value: 5,
    section: "five"
  },
  {
    key: "online",
    value: 5,
    section: "one"
  },
  {
    key: "online",
    value: 5,
    section: "Two"
  },
  {
    key: "online",
    value: 5,
    section: "three"
  },
  {
    key: "online",
    value: 5,
    section: "four"
  },
  {
    key: "online",
    value: 5,
    section: "five"
  },
  {
    key: "call",
    value: 5,
    section: "one"
  },
  {
    key: "call",
    value: 5,
    section: "Two"
  },
  {
    key: "call",
    value: 5,
    section: "three"
  },
  {
    key: "call",
    value: 5,
    section: "four"
  },
  {
    key: "call",
    value: 5,
    section: "five"
  },
];

const uniqueKeys = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { key, value } = curr;
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(uniqueKeys).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);

console.log(result);
```